# Any performance benefits to removing items from C# Dictionary after lookup if they only need to be read once

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, lookup

I have a Dictionary of objects with strings as the keys. This Dictionary is first populated with anywhere from 50 to tens of thousands of entries. Later on my program looks for values within this dictionary, and after having found an item in the dictionary I no longer have any need to persist the object that I just found in the dictionary. My question then is, would I be able to get better total execution time if I remove entries from the dictionary once I no longer have use for them, perhaps cutting down memory usage or just making subsequent lookups slightly faster, or would the extra time spent removing items be more impactful?

I understand the answer to this may depend upon certain details such as how many total lookups are done against the dictionary, the size of the key, and the size of the object, I will try to provide these below, but is there a general answer to this? Is it unnecessary to try and improve performance in this way, or are there cases where this would be a good idea?

Key is variable length string, either 6 characters or ~20 characters.
Total lookups is completely up in the air, I may have to only check 50x or so or I may have to look 10K times completely independent of the size of the dictionary, i.e. dictionary may have 50 items and I may do 10K lookups, or I may have 10K items and only do 50 lookups.

One additional note is that if I do remove items from the dictionary and I am ever left with an empty dictionary I can then signal to a waiting thread to no longer wait for me while I process the remaining items (involves parsing through a long text file while looking up items in the dictionary to determine what to do with the parsed data).

Comment: Try both and measure, then you'll know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary lookups are essentially O(1).  Removing items from the dictionary will have a tiny (if any) impact on lookup speed.

In the end, it's very likely that removing items will be slower than just leaving them in.

The only reason I'd suggest removing items would be if you need to reduce your memory footprint.

Answer (score 1):

I found some interesting items over at DotNetPerls that seem to relate to your question.

> The order you add keys to a Dictionary is important. It affects the
>   performance of accessing those keys. Because the Dictionary uses a
>   chaining algorithm, the keys that were added last are often faster to
>   locate.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-order

> Dictionary size influences lookup performance. Smaller Dictionaries
>   are faster than larger Dictionaries. This is true when they are tested
>   for keys that always exist in both. Reducing Dictionary size could
>   help improve performance.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-size

I thought this last tidbit was really interesting. It didn't occur to me to consider my key length.

> Generally, shorter [key] strings perform better than longer ones.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-string-key

Good question!

Comment: "Smaller Dictionaries are faster than larger Dictionaries" Who wrote this sh*t?

Comment: @spender There are benchmarks over at DotNetPerls and the author covers various scenarios when the size could impact performance.

Comment: Ok. So take the benchmark that ["proves" this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-size), and change the code by simply reversing the order of the tests so that the smaller dictionary is tested before the larger one. Who wins now? Still the small one? No, now the bigger one is faster. All the article really demonstrates to me is that the author doesn't know how to write benchmarks. His/her findings are completely wrong, and will lead users up the garden path of micro-optimizing a non-existent problem, leading to brittle, complex code that isn't needed. Don't believe everything you read.

Comment: BTW, apologies for the antagonistic tone in my first comment... I hope my 2nd comment in more constructive.

Comment: No worries. I'm just pointing out some articles I saw that may or may not help the OP. I haven't validated anything the author tried.

Comment: @spender You piqued my curiosity, so I copied the author's code, ran it, reversed it and ran it again. You are right! The second test appears to run faster, regardless of which test it is. How did you know that by looking at it?

Comment: @DougDawson Because he probably did it before writing his rant :-)

Comment: Hey! I think I found the source of the confusion. If you flip the code parts that do the tests, the output from the console is still {test1_result},{test2_result} because it writes the results out on a separate line. So, the second test is still showing faster, even with the tests flipped. It just looks wrong because you're expecting the s2 result to write out first.

Comment: So the real moral of this question is "don't believe ANYTHING you read", or at least be skeptical until tested and verified yourself.  So just put your dang mask back on and keep coding!